# Approximate Trig Functions without the use of Taylor Series

Tags: trigonometry, taylor-expansion, approximation, trigonometric-series

I am familiar with how a trig function, i.e. $\sin(x)$, can be approximated by a MacLauren series;

\begin{align}
\sin(x_0) &\approx \sin(0) + \cos(0) x_0 - \frac{1}{2}\sin(0) x_0^2 - \frac{1}{3!}\cos(0) x_0^3 + \dots \\&= x_0 - \frac{1}{6} x_0^3 +\dots.
\end{align}
However, this makes me wonder if there is any other way to approximate trig functions. I would be surprised if a mathematical approximation did not exist until after the advent of calculus. Is there any way to approximate trig functions without the use of a Taylor Series?

Comment: My friend, that is the definition of sinx.

Comment: @JohnMitchell isn't that more of something _derived_ from the definition of $\sin x$? I would think the more fundamental definition would be: given $\theta$ radians, $\sin(\theta) = y/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ for a right triangle with base length $x$ and height $y$

Comment: That’s the geometric meaning of sinx, not the definition. The modern definition of sinx is precisely the power series you’ve given.

Comment: @JohnMitchell Trigonometry has been used for thousands of years without calculus having been discovered and mathematical work being primarily geometric. Surely there is another way to approximate trig functions?

Comment: You can truncate the power series at some point. In this way you’ll obtain an approximation.

Comment: @JohnMitchell proofs for the Taylor Series are calculus-based, though, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84346/discussion-between-andrew-gazelka-and-john-mitchell).

Comment: Pre-calculus, what you do is to use geometric constructions, the Pythagorean Theorem, and other tools (possibly including trial and error) to work out the exact values for some specific angles and approximate values (to some reasonable precision) for some others until you can fill in all the lines of a suitable trig table. At least, that's what you do if you're Ptolemy. If you're anybody else, you just look it up in the table that Ptolemy published, interpolating between values if necessary.

Comment: Even in the computer age, if you call a trig function from a software library I doubt they just take your input and drop it in a truncated MacLauren series. There will likely be table lookups and more carefully-tuned interpolation formulas.

Comment: At least calculators use this method as far as I know

Comment: The Wikipedia article on History of Trigonometry has some information on the compiling of the first trig tables, as well as some of the methods (non-calculus based) used by the ancient mathematicians. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_trigonometry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A special case of the angle-sum formulas $\cos (x+y)=\cos x \sin y -\sin x \cos y $ and $ \sin (x+y)=\sin x \cos y + \cos x \sin y$ (which is for all $x,y$), when $x=y\in (0,\pi /2)$ by elementary geometry:

In $\triangle ABC$ with $BA=CA=1 ,$ 
 with $D$ being the mid-point of $ BC$, and $\angle BAD=x,$ we have $BD =\sin x.$ And  the Cosine Formula  gives $ BD^2=\frac {1}{4}BC^2=$ $=\frac {1}{4}(BA^2+CA^2-2BA\cdot CA \cos \angle BAC)=$ $=\frac {1}{2}(1-\cos 2x).$  Therefore $\sin^2 x =\frac {1-\cos 2x}{2}.$

So when $z=2x\in (0,\pi)$ we have the half-angle formulas $\sin z/2=\sqrt {(1-\cos z)/2}$ and $\cos z/2=\sqrt {1-\sin^2 z/2}=\sqrt {(1+\cos z)/2}.$

The Cosine Formula is a direct consequence of "Pythagoras". And $\sin^2 z/2+\cos^2 z/2=1$ IS "Pythagoras".

Between 21 and 22 centuries ago Archimedes used this to obtain the sin , cos, and tan of $\pi/(3\cdot  2^n)$ for $n=1,2,3,4$ starting with $\cos \pi /6=\sqrt 3\;/2,$ obtaining $3+\frac {10}{71}<48\sin \pi/48<\pi <48 \tan \pi/48<3+\frac {1}{7}.$

The general angle-sum formulas can be proved by elementary geometry. There is a very simple proof in the old classic Trigonometry, by Hobson (likely still available from Dover Publications, still a great source for cheap re-prints).

With the general angle-sum formulas, and knowing $\sin \pi /3$ and $\sin \pi/4 ,$ we can use the half-angle formulas to compute $\sin (\,A\pi/(3\cdot 2^m)+B\pi/(4\cdot 2^n)\,)$ for any $A,B\in \Bbb Z$ and any $m,n \in \Bbb Z^+\cup \{0\},$ which can be as close to any $\sin x$ as we like.

For if $x=x'+d \;$ then  $|\sin x-\sin x'|=$  $=|(\sin x'\cos d+\cos x'\sin d)-\sin x'|=$ $=|(\sin x')(-1+\cos d)+\cos x' \sin d|=$ $=|(\sin x')(-2\sin^2 d/2)+\cos x' \sin d| \leq$ $\leq  |\sin x'|\cdot  d^2/2+|\cos x'|\cdot |\sin d|\;\leq\; d^2/2+|d|.$

Also, one of the Comments recommends the wiki article History Of trigonometry.